# Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView1'. Remove one definition

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'm using a gridview and SqlDataSource to bind the data table information to the gridview.
On gridview update event I have the following code :

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
  {
                    var ID = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex]["No"];
                    string costring = "the conn string";
                    string query = "UPDATE mytable SET Age = @Age WHERE No = " + ID;
                    using (SqlConnection dataConnection = new SqlConnection(costring))
                    {
                        using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, dataConnection))
                        {
                            dataConnection.Open();
                            int valueID = 18;
                            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("Age", valueID);
                            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;
                            GridView1.DataBind();
                            dataConnection.Close();
                        }
                    }
                 }
```

- If I click the update event I get : "Both DataSource and DataSourceID
  are defined on 'GridView1'.  Remove one definition." here
  "GridView1.DataBind();"! but when I refresh the webpage the code
  worked but I always get this error.
- I've searched on google and I found that I can't use both..but I need
  to see the information on the gridview and I can't remove the
  sqldatasource binding and also I need to make the code work.
- I've tried DataGridviewID = null; and I don't get any error but
  nothing is changed the code is not executed..nothing happens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you really need to assign data source again if you emit this statement

```
  GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;
  GridView1.DataBind();
```

and use

```
  SqlDataSource1.Update();
```

There is an example of using datasource, i hope that will help you [Datasource example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.update.aspx)

Comment: Do you have  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" of grid? and do you expect grid with update age

Comment: you have to give update command in your datasource like UpdateCommand="UPDATE Employees SET Address=@Address WHERE EmployeeID=@EmployeeID">

Comment: No I don't have that . do I need to do it?

Comment: i have updated my answer and added a link for using data source i hope this will help you

Comment: yes I read it so I replaced the update command and parameters.add the No , ID ) and..nothing happens