# How to connect a GridView to two different sqldatasources in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, ado.net

I would like to know how I can connect a single `GridView` to two `SqlDataSource` objects?

At the moment I experience an error stating that both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView1', so I removed one definition. But I dont want remove any of the definitions, since both are important.

Aspx Markup

SqlDataSource1

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBCS %>" 
                DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [vendor_master] WHERE [vendorID] = @vendorID" 
                InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [vendor_master] ([Vname], [Email], [Mobile], [Landline], [Address], [Pincode]) VALUES (@Vname, @Email, @Mobile, @Landline, @Address, @Pincode)" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [vendor_master]" 
                UpdateCommand="UPDATE [vendor_master] SET [Vname] = @Vname, [Email] = @Email, [Mobile] = @Mobile, [Landline] = @Landline, [Address] = @Address, [Pincode] = @Pincode WHERE [vendorID] = @vendorID">
                <DeleteParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="vendorID" Type="Int32" />
                </DeleteParameters>
                <InsertParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Vname" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Mobile" Type="Int64" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Landline" Type="Int64" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Address" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Pincode" Type="Int32" />
                </InsertParameters>
                <UpdateParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Vname" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Mobile" Type="Int64" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Landline" Type="Int64" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Address" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Pincode" Type="Int32" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="vendorID" Type="Int32" />
                </UpdateParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

SqlDataSource2

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBCS %>" SelectCommand="FindVendor" 
                SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtFindVendor" Name="name" PropertyName="Text" 
                        Type="String" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

C# Code

```
protected void btnAddVendor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsValid)
    {
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["Vname"].DefaultValue = txtName.Text;
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["Email"].DefaultValue = txtEmail.Text;
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["Mobile"].DefaultValue = txtMobile.Text;
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["Landline"].DefaultValue = txtLandline.Text;
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["Address"].DefaultValue = txtAddress.Text;
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["Pincode"].DefaultValue = txtPincode.Text;

        SqlDataSource1.Insert();
    }
}

protected void btnFindName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource2;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to change the datasource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpliy on every click event instead of `GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource2` Change ...

```
protected void btnFindName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource2";
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must join 2 table in one SQLDatasource.like this:

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderDate
  FROM Orders
  INNER JOIN Customers
  ON Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is `Both DataSource and DataSourceID` is clear. The problem is in you html of `Gridview`.

Remove one of the property either `DataSource` or `DataSourceID`.

Similar Question on SO

1. [Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView1'. Remove one definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10208249/both-datasource-and-datasourceid-are-defined-on-gridview1-remove-one-definiti)

### Edit 1

Or you try to bind data to data grid using `sqldatasource` from design side as well as using c# code from code behind side..

```
<asp:gridview  runat="server" autogeneratecolumns="False" 
     DataSourceID="Datasource1">
```

Here `DataSourceID` is specified and in code behind `GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource2;` is causing the problem.